# How do i make php redirect to a new page

Tags: php, html, forms

so i'm making a contact form for some guy and I want it to give me an error message when some fields are empty. now it works and stuff, but it goes to blank page everytime. I've tried searching and couldn't find an answer.
my php code:

```
<?php
$from = $_POST['email_adress'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$select = $_POST['select'];
$message2 = $_POST['message2'];
$name = $_POST['firstname'];
$name2 = $_POST['lastname'];
if ($_POST['firstname'] == "")
{
    echo "<script>
             alert('A First Name is Mandatory'); 
     </script>";
}
elseif  ($_POST['subject'] == ""){
    echo "<script>
             alert('A Subject is Mandatory'); 
     </script>";
}
elseif ($_POST['email_adress'] == "") {
    echo "<script>
             alert('An Email Adress is Mandatory'); 
     </script>";
}
elseif ($_POST['message2'] == "") {
    echo "<script>
             alert('A Message is Mandatory'); 
             <a href='contactus.html'>;
     </script>";

} else {
$email_subject = "A submittion form";
$to ="sudaiguy1@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: sudaiguy1@gmail.com";
$email_body = 'You have been contacted by $name $name2 and his email is $from. \n The message he wanted to say was in the general subject of $select and more specifically $subject and the message is $message2';
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body, $headers);
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php header("Location: yourpage"); ?>
```

After sending the email there's no content on your page, so you have to redirect the user to a Page with some content, or add content bellow your mail send code.

Comment: works but it doesnt activate the alert

Comment: have you tried to access the page without posting anything?

Comment: what do you mean? without putting anything in the form?

Comment: nvm, try using

!isset($_POST['firstname']) instead of checking $_POST['firstname'] = ""

Comment: and also try to access this new page, through your browser. If this code is for example in sendmail.php. open it with your browser.

Comment: it works well, but the problem is the error message doesnt show up anymore

Comment: maybe you have suppressed alerts from your browser accidentally. Try with a different browser, Also check your page source if the script is writted on your html.

Comment: no, when i remove the header() it works

Comment: You should place the header location, INSIDE your ELSE code block

Comment: but then it just does what i dont want it to do.... whenever the alert opens up and i press ok it goes to blank page

Comment: Then you should make the redirection through javascript

window.location.href =  "yourpage";

Comment: I need to put it inside a script right?

Comment: yes after the alert.

Comment: what im trying to do is give it the alert then stay in the same page, i dont really want to redirect it

Comment: When you post something on a different page, it's always a blank page...
You should merge your 2 files into 1

You should make the top of your file to check if (isset($_POST['subject']) ... or something like that...
And then place in the if codeblock all your code.

Then you should place an ELSE statement open brackets, close php tag ?>

Place your html code,

open php tags
<?php
}
?>

Also you should consider on your input fields to add on their value="<?php echo $_POST['smth...']; ?>"

Comment: Also you should consider making a Client Side javascript validation before posting the page... If you want to avoid this...
So it can't post to the new page when insufficient data entered.

Comment: nevermind i found something else, ty anyway

Comment: echo '<script language="javascript">';
 echo 'alert("First Name is mandatory.");';
 echo 'window.location.href="contactus.html";';
 echo '</script>'; works well